# unit testing a function that takes IEnumerable<IClient> clients parameter

Tags: c#, unit-testing, integration-testing

I have a function that saves multiple clients one client at a time. I am struggling to create and populate one of the parameters IEnumerable with string type client properties: clientKey , clientName, and clientTypeCode

```
public void SaveMultipleClients(IEnumerable<IClient> clients, TransactionMetadata metadata)
    {
        try
        {
            if (clients == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("clients");
            }

            var abstractClients = clients.ToList();
            var concreteClients = new List<Client>();
            for (int i = 0; i < abstractClients.Count; i++)
            {
                concreteClients.Add(abstractClients[i].ToConcreteType<IClient, Client>());
    var cleanClients = this.RemoveErroneousClient(concreteClients[i]);
                foreach (var client in cleanClients)
                {
                    this.SaveClient(client, metadata);
                }
            }

            this.SavePending(concreteClients, metadata);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e.WrapException();
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: what error do you get? And where?

Comment: You have a concrete implementation of IClient interface somewhere you are creating?  Or are you mocking this interface?  Add them to a List<IClient>

Comment: If your question is 'how to build a collection of clients in your unit test', you can either build a test ICient implementation or use a mocking framework (MS fakes for instance) to build one inside your test

Comment: vc 74 Yes I would like to build a collection of clients in my unit test. Can you show code example?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to instantiate and populate a list of clients and passed it to the clients parameter.

```
var myClientsList = new List<IClient>();
        myClientsList.Add(individualClient);
        myClientsList.Add(individualClient1);

        var clients = clientDataManager.SaveMultipleClientsOneAtATime(myClientsList, new TransactionMetadata(DateTime.UtcNow));
```

Comment: You don't like this approach?